# Python log file in descending order

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have an application written in python that logs errors in a log file, I am using the python logging module

Example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='\logs\filename.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.error('error connecting to server')
```

This is working fine and the log file is logging the errors,  which mean the last error is logged on the last line of the file.

is there some kind of setting where I can tell the logging module to always write at the top of the file, this way the last error is always on the first line.

Comment: It is very ineffective to append to the beginning of the file. Do you know the command `tail`, which will help you to retrieve the line(s) from the end of file?

Comment: Even better (depending on what you want), a call to `tail -f` retrieves lines from the end of file, and display new lines as they get appended. Why do you want a log file in reverse order ?

Comment: And even *more* better, use [`multitail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitail).

Comment: The log file is huge and we use notepad++ to open and view the log, this way we don't have to scroll all the way to the bottom to view an error.

Comment: If your logfile is big, you should [rotate it](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler).

Comment: I will explore rotate it - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very inefficient to write to the front of a flle as others have said. Every single write will have to first seek to the front of the file and then insert the new data before the other data. The underlying I/O of your operating system is designed to make appends cheap.

That said, if you insist on doing it, look at the docs here [Logging Handlers](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html?highlight=filehandler#module-logging.handlers). You can implement your own version of `logging.handlers.FileHandler` that will seek to the beginning before each write. Then you could call `logging.addHandler()` and place an instance of your class. If you only care about the most recent 10 or so log entries you could even truncate the file before you write.